# how to show date in expirydate column

Tags: yii

how to show date in expirydate column which is 5 time more of the original date.
i.e. i have a column name created and have a deafult date(7/19/2023) but in expiry date column i want to show a date like (7/24/2013) always when i save the expiry date will be 5 more to the original date?

```
public function rules(){
    return array(
            array('title','required'),
            array('jobid,notes,companyid,createdon,expirydate','safe'),
            array('createdon','default',
                    'value'=>new CDbExpression('NOW()'),
                    'setOnEmpty'=>false,'on'=>'update'),
            array('createdon,expirydate','default',
                    'value'=>new CDbExpression('NOW()'),
                    'setOnEmpty'=>false,'on'=>'insert')
    );
}
```

Comment: this date(1970/01/06)s is show after using this code.
Thanh Khánh

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtotime to calculate expirydate:

```
$time = strtotime('+5 days', strtotime($model->createdon));
$model->expirydate = date('m/d/Y', $time );
```